# How can i install boto library on windows for python?

Tags: python, installation, boto

I'm using `windows 7` system, and `python` programming. How can i install `boto` library on `windows7`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downlload the boto package to your computer from say: http://boto.googlecode.com/files/boto-2.6.0.tar.gz

Unzip it.
Traverse to the unzipped folder using CMD prompt.

and run the following command:

```
setup.py install
```

Verify the installation by trying to import boto in python.

If you have pip installed you can run:

```
pip install -U boto
```

EDIT: if setup.py install is not recognized try `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 5):

The answer is given in the [boto repository on github](https://github.com/boto/boto)

```
$ git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git
$ cd boto
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: wait... Which folder can i user git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git

Comment: It can be to any folder that you want to keep the installation of the boto library. If you don't have git installed  you can use Jon Kartago's answer.

Comment: I was done ! I user commant: c:\env\scripts>C:\python27\scripts\easy_install boto

Answer (score 4):

Actually the answer of this question is very straight forward if you could search for a while. But I assume you really new to python. I will suggest to use some python package manager. One example is pip http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/. After finished the installation just run this inside command line

```
pip install boto
```

To check installation result open python console and run

```
import boto
```

If no error messages then you have successfully install boto